# How to set an object passed via props into hooks local state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Passed props set to the state but cannot access inside properties

passed model as follows

```js
let v = {
    "id": "6ccd12a3-802b-4ff6-ab6d-0f66f9df1e99",
    "mac": "a4:5e:60:f2:89:bf"
}
```

Im invoking the model as follows

```js
<VisitorModal visitor={v}/>
```

model is here

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Modal, Form, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

const VisitorModal = ({ visitor }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ modalOpen: false, v: visitor });

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.name);
    console.log(e.target.value);
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, v: visitor }));
  }, [visitor]);

  return (
    <Modal
      trigger={<Button onClick={() => setState({ modalOpen: true })}> View/Edit Visitor </Button>}
      centered={false}
      open={state.modalOpen}
      onClose={() => setState({ modalOpen: false })}
    >
      {JSON.stringify(state)}
      <Modal.Header> View/Edit Visitor </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Content image>
        <Modal.Description>
          <Form>
            <Form.Group widths="equal">
              <Form.Input label="MAC" placeholder="mac" value={state.v.mac} onChange={handleOnChange} />
              <Form.Input label="Name" placeholder="Name" value={state.v.name} onChange={handleOnChange} />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Button>Save</Form.Button>
              <Form.Button onClick={() => setState({ modalOpen: false })}>Cancel</Form.Button>
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Description>
      </Modal.Content>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default VisitorModal;
```

`error is TypeError: Cannot read property 'mac' of undefined`

Comment: in `handleOnChange` are you sure you want to update state directly with `e.target.name` as a key? don't you mean `state.v[e.target.name]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you're not setting a value for `v` in your initial state object, nor in your event handlers. `useState()` does not merge object values, it overwrites them. Therefore you have two options: use `useReducer`, or use separate state objects for `modalOpen` and `v`.

This should fix it, using the latter option, assuming you update your `render()` method appropriately:

```
const VisitorModal = ({ visitor }) => {
  const [ modalOpen, setModalOpen ] = useState(false);
  const [ v, setV ] = useState(visitor);

  // Update `v` when the visitor prop changes.
  useEffect(() => {
    setV(visitor);
  }, [visitor]);
  const handleChange = e => setV({ ...v, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  return (
       <Form.Input label="MAC" placeholder="mac" value={v.mac} onChange={handleChange} />
  );
}
```

Your event handlers can now refer to `setV()` and `setModalOpen()` independently.

Comment: when you `console.log(state);` before the `return()` what does it output?

Comment: Im changing that value. When it passed as a prop I cant process , so I want it inside the state

Comment: {"modalOpen":true}

Comment: if there's other relevant code that's causing it to fail, please add that to your original question

Comment: added the component

Answer (score 0):

you have missed to retrieve the previous values while toggling the model so object is missing the visiter properties. just try this

```
return (
    <Modal
      trigger={<Button onClick={() => setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, modalOpen: true }))}> View/Edit Visitor </Button>}
      centered={false}
      open={state.modalOpen}
      onClose={() => setState(setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, modalOpen: false }))}
    >
      {JSON.stringify(state)}
      <Modal.Header> View/Edit Visitor </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Content image>
        <Modal.Description>
          <Form>
            <Form.Group widths="equal">
              <Form.Input label="MAC" placeholder="mac" value={state.v.mac} onChange={handleOnChange} />
              <Form.Input label="Name" placeholder="Name" value={state.v.name} onChange={handleOnChange} />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Button>Save</Form.Button>
              <Form.Button onClick={() => setState(setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, modalOpen: false }))}>Cancel</Form.Button>
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Description>
      </Modal.Content>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```